# Do Ganeti Nodes need to have identical hardware?

Tags: linux, virtualization, cluster

Do Ganeti Nodes need to have identical hardware or just close.  For example, could I run a three machine cluster with two Pentium 4's and a Pentium 3 machine with disk space and RAM the same.

Thanks in advance for your help guys!

Answer (score 2):

I run it on 3 totally different nodes, it works just fine.  Having similar amounts of RAM helps the most if you plan on using drbd and migrating VMs around.

The newer version even lets you mix xen and kvm, which helps if you have heterogeneous hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is "it shouldn't" however I'd look at upgrading to 64-bit capable hardware first, anything new should let you consolidate a lot first.

Answer (score 0):

I have a mixed configuration -- some nodes even on different networks. Different hardware, different disks, different memory, it just works.